# chartjs linechart shifting by a day

Tags: chart.js

As you can see in the example below, my dates are starting at 2022-11-24, however in chart it starts from 2022-11-23, and all rest of dates get shifted by about a day. What's causing this issue ? Thanks !

```js
let chart_dates = ['2022-11-24T00:00:00Z', '2022-11-25T00:00:00Z', '2022-11-26T00:00:00Z', '2022-11-27T00:00:00Z', '2022-11-28T00:00:00Z', '2022-11-29T00:00:00Z', '2022-11-30T00:00:00Z'];
        
        let chartDataSet = [{"label":"A","data":[0,23,0,0,25,31,2],"lineTension":0.2,"borderColor":"#4e73df"},{"label":"B","data":[0,1,0,0,18,6,0],"lineTension":0.2,"borderColor":"#1cc88a"}];
       
        
        new Chart(document.getElementById("chartJSContainer"), {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: chart_dates,
            datasets: chartDataSet
          },
          options:{
            scales: {
              x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                  unit: 'day'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

```html
     <body>
              <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script>     
              <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>
       </body>
```

Comment: Your chart starts at the 24, I don't see any issue

Comment: Please add a reproducaible sample because the code you linked works fine if you run it https://imgur.com/a/7Q6nEKE

Comment: That seems to be the issue because for me all the dates are shifted 1 hour to the right, so instead of 00 it is 01

Comment: @PitDigger Could you solve your problem? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs due to the timeoffset of localtime to Zulu/UTC Time. Your timezone has *(probably)* a negative offset, that why it seems off for some hours.

My time offset is positive (+02:00),so it looks fine for me (chart begins at 24.11 more or less). Just use localtime datetimes in your data than you should not have this issue anymore.*(Or just remove the time part if you don't need/use it -> '2022-11-24')*

**Just for demo I remove the (Zulu) `Z` in the date dataset, to show case this:**
*(Due to this change, the Datetime items are now interpreted as localtime)*

```js
let chart_dates = [
      '2022-11-24T00:00:00', '2022-11-25T00:00:00', '2022-11-26T00:00:00',
      '2022-11-27T00:00:00', '2022-11-28T00:00:00', '2022-11-29T00:00:00',
      '2022-11-30T00:00:00', ];

  let chartDataSet = [
      {"label":"A","data":[0,23,0,0,25,31,2],"lineTension":0.2,"borderColor":"#4e73df"},
      {"label":"B","data":[0,1,0,0,18,6,0],"lineTension":0.2,"borderColor":"#1cc88a"},
  ];
  
  new Chart(document.getElementById("chartJSContainer"), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: chart_dates,
        datasets: chartDataSet
      },
      options:{
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: 'day'
            }
          }
        }
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script>     
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>
  
<div class="chart" style="height:184px;width:500px">
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```