# Chart.js - How to move x axis tick marks position to above the x axis

Tags: chart.js

I drew a line chart and want to move x axis tick marks position, but I can not find related configuration. Please see the picture below.

[AS-IS/TO-BE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp8Rk.png)

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js">
```

```
<canvas id="myChart" style="height:500px"></canvas>
```

```
chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: "Count",
                pointStyle: 'circle',
                showLine: true,
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0,
                borderColor: '#7265ce',
                pointRadius: 4,
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointBackgroundColor: '#7265ce',
                data: data
            }]
        },
        options: {
            parsing: {
                xAxisKey: 'timestamp',
                yAxisKey: 'value'
            },
            spanGaps: false,
            responsive: false,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    bounds: 'ticks',
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        parser: 'yyyyMMddHHmmss',
                        unit: 'minute',
                        stepSize: 5,
                        displayFormats: {
                            minute: 'HH:mm',
                            second: 'mm:ss'
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Timestamp'
                    },
                    grid: {
                        drawOnChartArea: false,
                        lineWidth: 1
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        display: true,
                        color: '#cecece'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        padding: 10,
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit:2,
                        color: '#cecece'
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Count',
                        align: 'end'
                    },
                    grid: {
                        drawOnChartArea: false
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```
    let data = [
    { "timestamp": "20230109150000", "value": 10 },
    { "timestamp": "20230109150100", "value": 17 },
    { "timestamp": "20230109150200", "value": 92 },
    { "timestamp": "20230109150300", "value": 60 },
    { "timestamp": "20230109150400", "value": 50 },
    { "timestamp": "20230109150500", "value": 91 }
    ];
```

Is it possible?
Is there any configuration in chartjs?
I'm using v3.9.1

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74640373/1679286 , it solves more or less the same problem. Since I asume the problem has to do with your time offset.

Comment: If you are suing "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js", you are not using version 3 but version 4, 4.1.2

Comment: If I understand your question and what you wanted was to center the tickmarks ... well, I don't think you can using standard options :) But you can change the default behavior of `chart.js` easy enough. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5y7oj3m1/) you have a quick-and-dirty example, using [derived axis types](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/derived-axis-type.html). Note that a more elaborate version would also adjust the ticks space avoiding the need to manually adjust the padding.